# xcode assistant editor is shaking

Tags: xcode, xcode7.2, xcode7.3

In Xcode 7.2.1 and 7.3, sometimes, when opening an assistant editor (third)  or adjusting the width of the assistant editor (third), the editor shakes and I can't do anything for a few seconds. When it happens, I stop it by re adjusting the width or closing the third view. How to avoid this?

Please download the [GIF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4aSJ3J-Ga07bW56aHNZU3REc2s/view?usp=sharing) or [VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4aSJ3J-Ga07bW56aHNZU3REc2s/view?usp=sharing) to see

Comment: I would suggest asking this on Apple's developer tool forums and reporting it as a bug in XCode.